# Javascript: How Are Context Menus Able To Appear Outside Of The Document and How Can I Do That For A Custom Context Menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a custom context menu that is added to the document on a right-click. If you were to right click near the edge of the document, it will overflow it and make me have to scroll to it. With default contexts menus, it will appear over the document on right-click. Is there a way of getting a custom context menu to do that?

I know I can fix the overflow problem (overflow: hidden;) but that won;t fix the custom context menu from appearing inside of the window.

Comment: First question: do you *need* a custom context menu? (Hint: you don't)

Comment: Well sounds like you need to detect if it overflows and move it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Please inform the developers of Google Docs that they're doing web wrong

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice personal opinion....

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I know I don't need one, but I made a C# form that has one and I'm trying to replicate it as an HTML version.

Comment: @epascarello I know that is a way of doing it. I may consider it but if there is a away to make it appear outside of the document, I am glad to use that way instead.

Comment: Outside the browser.... no

Comment: @epascarello Is there an explanation to why a default one will but a custom one won't?

Comment: because the menu is a windowed object and you can not do that.... Imagine going to a site that could move crap outside the window.... ;) What you want to do is impossible.... all you can do is what I mentioned and move your menu into the visible space on the page.

Comment: The real context menu is part of the browser application itself, so not limited to the window viewport boundaries.  A DOM-based context menu is part of a web page, so is limited to the window viewport boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to know, if given the document/window dimmensions and the mouse position, if your menu will flow out.

If the context menu has a fixed width, for the x axis, you just need to control that mouse_x + context_menu_width is lower than window_width.
If it's bigger, just set the context_menu x position to window_width - context_menu_width.

Same applies for y axis (somehow).

If the menu doesn't have a fixed width, you may need to create the context_menu first, and then set the position the amount of pixels is off.